# Running conda install as an admin on my ubuntu server, I get "Missing write permissions: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3"

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, anaconda, conda

I have installed Anaconda3 on my ubuntu server. 
When I attempt to install or upgrade any package using conda, for example:

```
conda install numpy=1.11.0
```

(of course you cannot do "sudo conda")

I receive the following error:

```
Error: Missing write permissions in: /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
#
# You don't appear to have the necessary permissions to install packages
# into the install area '/home/ubuntu/anaconda3'.
# However you can clone this environment into your home directory and
# then make changes to it.
# This may be done using the command:
#
# $ conda create -n my_root --clone=/home/ubuntu/anaconda3
```

Comment: Have you tried using `chown` and `chmod` to change the owner to your user account and grant writing permission?

Comment: sudo chown ubuntu /home/ubuntu/anaconda3

Comment: @cel `sudo chown -R ubuntu /home/ubuntu/anaconda3`
   `sudo chmod -R +x /home/ubuntu/anaconda3`
worked!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @cel pointed out, providing the correct permissions is all that is necessary:

```
sudo chown -R ubuntu /home/ubuntu/anaconda3 
sudo chmod -R +x /home/ubuntu/anaconda3
```